# Invalid redeclaration of init() for iOS Swift Core Data Implementation RELEASE build only

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, compiler-errors, release

I am running into a strange situation that I am unsure how to fix.

I have an iOS app I am working on in Swift that uses Core Data that I have been successfully building and running as a Debug build for some time now.  I have now attempted to build for profiling of the release build, and subsequently just tried to do a release build without profiling, and either release build fails with the error 'Invalid redeclaration of init()' for a struct that defines the storage implementation portion of my code that sets up the storage components of Core Data.

Here is the code that compiles and runs fine in debug, but fails to build in release...

```
struct MyStorage { //<-- Invalid redeclaration of init() build error in release build only

static var shared = MyStorage()

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
private lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyStorage")
    container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
        print("CoreData: Inited \(storeDescription)")
        guard error == nil else {
            print("CoreData: trying to create persistentContainer named Model and got Unresolved error \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

    }
    return container
}()

private lazy var persistenStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    do {
        return try NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.coordinator(name:"MyStorage")
    } catch {
        print ("CoreData: trying to create persistenStoreCoordinator named Model and got Unresolved error \(error)")
    }

    return nil
}()

private lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let coordinator = self.persistenStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator

    print ("CoreData: initing and returning managedObjectContext")

    return managedObjectContext
}()

enum SaveStatus {
    case saved, rolledBack, hasNoChanges
}

var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
    mutating get {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {  
            return persistentContainer.viewContext
        } else {
            return managedObjectContext
        }
    }
}

mutating func save() -> SaveStatus {
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
            return .saved
        } catch {
            context.rollback()
            return .rolledBack
        }
    }
    return .hasNoChanges
}
```

I cleaned the build (and option-cleaned to clean the build folder), both to no avail.  Can anyone help shed light on why the release build fails yet the debug build succeeds with this same code?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

**UPDATE**: Per the suggestion below, I changed the MyStorage struct to a class and removed mutating and now the code can build in release configuration and can be profiled for released build.

Comment: Have you restarted Xcode, restarted the Mac since the problem came up? Does the problem go away if you make MyStorage a class? Try to create an empty default initializer and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Restarting Xcode didn't help.  However, changing from a struct to a class (and removing mutating) allows the code to build in release configuration and for profiling release build now.  Thanks again!

Comment: It might have been a bug in the compiler I don‘t know. May be worth reporting if you want to take the time. Glad it worked!

Comment: This report is extremely interesting but unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue. Can you post a (reduced?) project on github or similar that will allow me to do so? If I can reproduce it, I'll submit a bug report for you if you don't want to do that.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Apple, however, they were unable to reproduce the problem as well.  I'll have to see if I can distill down to a smaller/targeted proj that can illustrate the problem.  Unfortunately, I won't have time to do so for a bit.